# Update item in RecyclerView after Networking

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I need a hint to how notify an item that has been changed after networking..

I have a RecylerView with items and for each item an image,
on item bind I am downloading the image, after the image has been downloaded successfully I what to notify only the relevant item and not the entire adapter.
but the items in the RecylerView can be moved so I can't use the position of the item.

Any ideas to how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I created an Adapter that returned each view before actually decoding the bitmap to put on it. I used an AsyncTask:

```
private class SetImageTask extends AsyncTask<ImageView, Integer, Bitmap> {


    private ImageView mImageView;
    private String mImagePath;
    @Override 
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(ImageView... params) {


        mImageView = params[0];
        mImagePath = (String) mImageView.getTag();
        return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mImagePath);
    } 


    @Override 
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {


        if (mImagePath != (mImageView.getTag())){
            return; 
        } 
        mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);


        mImageView.invalidate();
    } 
}
```

You can set any Object you want with `View.setTag()`. I'm sure you could modify this to work for you.

EDIT:
this is where I start the AsyncTask in `getView()`:

```
    holder.image.setTag(imagePath);
    new SetImageTask().execute(holder.image);
```

Comment: Thanks it gave me an idea..

You solution is not fit for my situation because I have a placeholder view that needs to be hidden when the image is loaded.